# Concat two dataframe with rows in particular location

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

df1:

```
id    Stu_Name   Class     Fees
1     Jack       primary   2333
2     mack       primary   2363
3     may        primary   2833
3     Mark       primary   1333
3     John       primary   9333
4     Moon       Secondary 6589 
5     daisy      Secondary 6565 
6     shawn      Secondary 6545 
6     roy        Secondary 6596
9     hary       higher    8526
10    Joy        higher    9654
10    nick       higher    7845
10    julie      higher    9633
```

df2:

```
id    Stu_Name   Class     Fees
11    eric       primary   2333
21    fick       primary   2363
42    Moon       Secondary 6589 
56    anki       Secondary 6565 
18    menk       higher    7845
17    rock       higher    9633
```

df_output:

```
id    Stu_Name   Class     Fees
1     Jack       primary   2333
2     mack       primary   2363
11    eric       primary   2333
21    fick       primary   2363
3     may        primary   2833
3     Mark       primary   1333
3     John       primary   9333
4     Moon       Secondary 6589 
5     daisy      Secondary 6565 
42    Moon       Secondary 6589 
56    anki       Secondary 6565
6     shawn      Secondary 6545 
6     roy        Secondary 6596
9     hary       higher    8526
18    menk       higher    7845
17    rock       higher    9633
10    Joy        higher    9654
10    nick       higher    7845
10    julie      higher    9633
```

I need to concat two df with row placement,for example:
you can see in df1 for class "primary" Id "3" is repeated for couple of times,
i need to append df2 class "primary" rows just before when the id in df1 is repeating.
same goes for other class.

Comment: Please do not tag this with version(s) of python you are *not* using.

Comment: @Scott Hunter ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mis-understood the goal.  Here is a revised response.  This is a long response, but the work is accomplished in three lines of code.

First, create and combine the two data frames:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# create the 2 data frames

data = '''id    Stu_Name   Class     Fees
1     Jack       primary   2333
2     mack       primary   2363
3     may        primary   2833
3     Mark       primary   1333
3     John       primary   9333
4     Moon       Secondary 6589 
5     daisy      Secondary 6565 
6     shawn      Secondary 6545 
6     roy        Secondary 6596
9     hary       higher    8526
10    Joy        higher    9654
10    nick       higher    7845
10    julie      higher    9633
'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', engine='python')


data = '''id    Stu_Name   Class     Fees
11    eric       primary   2333
21    fick       primary   2363
42    Moon       Secondary 6589 
56    anki       Secondary 6565 
18    menk       higher    7845
17    rock       higher    9633
'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', engine='python')

# combine the 2 data frames
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Now, create two helper columns, and sort:

```
# create the 1st helper column (for sorting at end)
# this will group (and sort) primary, Secondary, higher
df['class_num'] = df['Class'].factorize()[0]

# create 2nd helper column (to identify repeated IDs)
df['id_count'] = df.groupby('id')['id'].transform('count')

# if the logic is correct, then drop 'class_num', 'id_count'
df = df.sort_values(['class_num', 'id_count']).set_index('id')
```

Results are:

```
print(df)

   Stu_Name      Class  Fees  class_num  id_count
id                                               
1      Jack    primary  2333          0         1
2      mack    primary  2363          0         1
11     eric    primary  2333          0         1
21     fick    primary  2363          0         1
3       may    primary  2833          0         3
3      Mark    primary  1333          0         3
3      John    primary  9333          0         3
4      Moon  Secondary  6589          1         1
5     daisy  Secondary  6565          1         1
42     Moon  Secondary  6589          1         1
56     anki  Secondary  6565          1         1
6     shawn  Secondary  6545          1         2
6       roy  Secondary  6596          1         2
9      hary     higher  8526          2         1
18     menk     higher  7845          2         1
17     rock     higher  9633          2         1
10      Joy     higher  9654          2         3
10     nick     higher  7845          2         3
10    julie     higher  9633          2         3
```

---

ORIG POST

You can use the Categorical type to provide a custom sort order:

```
class_idx = pd.CategoricalIndex(
    categories = ['primary', 'Secondary', 'higher'], 
    ordered=True)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).astype(
    {'id': 'int', 
     'Stu_Name': 'string', 
     'Class': class_idx, 
     'Fees': 'int'}).sort_values('Class')

print(df.head())

   id Stu_Name    Class  Fees
0   1     Jack  primary  2333
1   2     mack  primary  2363
2   3      may  primary  2833
3   3     Mark  primary  1333
4   3     John  primary  9333
```

Comment: I don't think this answers my question because the rows has not sorted as my output.